# Swift - Why does map act differently when called on an optional array, rather than directly on an array?

Tags: swift

Here's an example:

```
let d = ["list": [["a": 1], ["a": 2]]]

d["list"].map { item in
    print("item is \(item)")
}

[["a": 1], ["a": 2]].map { item in
    print("item is \(item)")
}
```

I would expect these to print the same thing, since `d["list"] == [["a": 1], ["a": 2]]`. Yet when I run it, the first one gives me:

```
item is [["a": 1], ["a": 2]]
```

The second:

```
item is ["a": 1]


item is ["b": 2]
```

Why is this?

[repl link](https://repl.it/repls/BogusUnconsciousPolygon)

Answer (score 2):

`d["list"]` returns an optional and the `map` function is not `Array.map` but `Optional.map`.

Adding a `?` would make the difference.

```
d["list"]?.map { item in
    print("item is \(item)")
}
```

Also note that in this case you should be using `forEach` and not `map`. And that would make the error obvious:

```
// compilation error "Value of optional type not unwrapped..."
d["list"].forEach { item in
    print("item is \(item)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is beacuse `d["list"]` returns an Optional.

You say `d["list"] == [["a": 1], ["a": 2]]`, but it is not. When you try the code

```
if d["list"] == [["a": 1], ["a": 2]] {
    print("true")
}
```

this code cannot compile. There is an error:

> error: contextual type '_OptionalNilComparisonType' cannot be used with array literal

You have to unwrap `d["list"]` with `!` or `?` and it will print correctly.